# Stage 3D - draw orbit lines 'mathematically'

Tags: vertex-shader, stage3d, agal

I'd like to know if there's a way, using Stage3D and AGAL, to draw just the perimeter of a circle without using an actual mesh; I’m thinking the vertex shader could, somehow, be ‘tricked’ into thinking it’s processing the vertices of a mesh, while always setting the op (output position) register to the same distance from a point in space on a specific plane. (I'd like to render the orbits of planets in a space game I'm making)
I can't get my head around how that might be done though. Any ideas?

Comment: Before I consider a Stage3D-based answer - why is it not possible to use the normal AS3 drawing interface? A call to drawCircle would be a lot easier! Also: how thick must the circle be?

Comment: It WOULD be possible to use the graphics methods, but I'm keen to put as much of the drawing through the GPU as possible as opposed to using the more bottle-necked Flash renderer. Also the orbital lines would be drawn in front of the Stage3D layer; lines could not disappear behind actual 3D objects. I'd be keen to hear your Stage3D-based ideas.

Comment: This doesn't get you around needing a mesh, but you could probably handle this with a quad and a simple sprite (0 alpha except along the orbit circle) as long as the orbit circles get drawn before the planets.

Comment: Alternatively you could create a fragment shader that would automagically draw them in based on the star system's center coordinate and distance to the planet. Shader first draws the orbit based on the circle equation, then draws the planet. You could store the results in a texture to avoid recalculation, too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This second option sounds like what I want, but I'm asking HOW I'd do that. To my understanding the vertex shader needs a mesh to iterate over to calculate each output position on screen. Is there some way of coding a vertex shader that doesn't involve a mesh?

Comment: You will absolutely still need a mesh, but I'm relatively sure this can be handled with a single quad and a fancy fragment shader... It'll end up something like this: make a quad covering (EXACTLY) the screen, send the quad to the vertex shader, pass the quad's (x,y) coordinates to the varying register, and pass the circle's center (a,b) and radius (r) to the constant register. Color pixels for which (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2-r^2=0. Unless the number of orbits needed is predictable, though, this would likely require multiple draw calls.

Comment: If I have some spare time this week, I'll see if I can throw some code together.